# A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'SloDWPool'

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a series of Azure SQL Data Warehouse databases (for our development/evaluation purposes).  Due to a recent unplanned extended outage (due to an issue with the Tenant Ring associated with some of these databases), I decided to resume the canary queries I had been running before but had quiesced for a couple of months due to frequent exceptions.

The canary queries are not running particularly frequently on any specific database, say every 15 minutes.  On one database, I've received two indications of issues completing the canary query in 24 hours.  The error is:

```
Msg 110802, Level 16, State 1, Server adwscdev1, Line 1110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'SloDWPool' (2000000007). Rerun the query.
```

This database is under essentially no load, running at more than 100 DWU.

Other databases on the same logical server may be running under a load, but I have not seen the error on them.

What is the explanation for this error?

Comment: There seems to be a high correlation with the error occurring in the canary query which is running in the default smallrc with REBUILD INDEX commands running in xlargerc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open a support ticket for this issue, support will have full access to the DMS logs and be able to see exactly what is going on. this behavior is not expected.

Comment: Agreed.  Problem sporadically continued over the weekend, only reported in the one database, but several ADW databases are hosted on the logical server.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree a support case would be reasonable I think you should also try scaling up to say DWU400 and retrying. I would also consider trying largerc or xlargerc on DWU100 and DWU400 as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-concurrency?). Note it gets more memory and resources per query.

Run the following then retry your query:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'largerc', 'yourLoginName'
```

Comment: The purpose of my canary query is primarily to determine if the database is up.  As a side benefit I also get to see the response time for work in the smallrc.  The canary query is small for a data warehouse environment, involving the join of two one-million row tables on their (logical) primary keys with one requiring a redistribution (due to the intentional choice of its distribution column).